# angular on click reduce the form field size

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am new to angular js , CSS and have basic Java-script knowledge.

I am trying to design a form page in where the form field, say username would reduce in size on click and increase on click somewhere else. I tried ng-hide and ng-show where I added different css styles to each class and it made the form field disappear and appear on click.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATED:

This is my input text box where i want the UserName to reduce in size and sit at the left top of the textbox on click.

```
<body>
<input type="text" value="Username" style="width: 100%; height: 50px ; 
 border:0;border-bottom: 1px solid black;" > </body>
```

Comment: Without any code we cannot help you. Post relevant code in your question by editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ng-hide and ng-show, you can use ng-class. Based on the last click, you can set a controller variable ("selected" in the example below) and set the class with its asociated styling as follows in your html file.

```
<input ... ng-class="{selected ? reducedSize : increasedSized}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use CSS

```
input{
  width: 200px;
  //added a smooth transition, need vendor prefixes
  transition: width 0.25s ease-in;
}
input:focus{
 width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two methods. One for *ng-click* and another one for *ng-blur*
and do whatever you want.

```
ng-click="inputClickFunction()" and ng-blur="inputBlurFunction()"
```